# Get string inside parentheses, removing parentheses, with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have these two strings...

```
var str1 = "this is (1) test";
var str2 = "this is (2) test";
```

And want to write a RegEx to extract what is INSIDE the parentheses as in `"1"` and `"2"` to produce a string like below.

```
var str3 = "12";
```

right now I have this regex which is returning the parentheses too...

```
var re = (/\((.*?)\)/g);

var str1 = str1.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);
var str2 = str2.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);

var str3 = str1+str2; //produces "(1)(2)"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a javascript regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

Javascript

```
var str1 = "this is (1) test",
    str2 = "this is (2) test",
    str3 = str1.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1] + str2.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1];

alert(str3);
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7zPZH/)</kbd>

See [MDN RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

> (x)    Matches x and remembers the match. These are called capturing
>   parentheses.
>
> For example, /(foo)/ matches and remembers 'foo' in "foo bar." The
>   matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements
>   [1](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7zPZH/), ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's properties $1,
>   ..., $9.
>
> Capturing groups have a performance penalty. If you don't need the
>   matched substring to be recalled, prefer non-capturing parentheses
>   (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\((\d+)\)[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/
```

This will capture any digit of one or more inside the parentheses.

Example: http://regexr.com?365uj

**EDIT:** In the example you will see the replace field has only the numbers, and not the parentheses--this is because the capturing group `$1` is only capturing the digits themselves.

**EDIT 2:**

Try something like this:

```
var str1 = "this is (1) test";
var str2 = "this is (2) test";

var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\((\d+)\)[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/;

str1 = str1.replace(re, "$1");
str2 = str2.replace(re, "$1");

console.log(str1, str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var re = (/\((.*?)\)/g);

    var str1 = str1.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);
    var new_str1=str1.substr(1,str1.length-1);
    var str2 = str2.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);
    var new_str2=str2.substr(1,str2.length-1);

    var str3 = new_str1+new_str2; //produces "12"
```

Comment: should be `str2.substr(1,str2.length-2)`