# How to get value without brackets using JQuery plugin inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following code:

```
$("#ce_clientphone").inputmask("+9(999)9999999")
...
console.log($('#ce_clientphone').unmask())
```

As you can see I try to get value from '#ce_clientphone' without brackets. How can I do it? I need to allow user to input valid phone, but to save it in the database I need to remove brackets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(selector).inputmask('unmaskedvalue');

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#unmaskedvalue

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Regex get string inside brackets,removing brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559762/javascript-regex-get-string-inside-brackets-removing-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

You could do regular expressions and `replace` to remove the brackets

```
"+9(999)9999999".replace(/[()]/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#ce_clientphone').unmask().replace(/[()]/g, '');
```

For example:

```
"+9(999)9999999".replace(/[()]/g, '');
```

Returns:

```
"+99999999999"
```

So, how does this work?

We're using a regex to replace the brackets:

```
/  // Start of regex
[  // Start of character group
() // match either of these characters in the group (So match `(` OR `)`)
]  // End of character group
/  // End of regex
g  // `Global` flag. This means the regex won't stop searching after the first replace
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="+9(999)9999999";
alert(str.replace(/[()]/g,''));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4kxr9o6/)