# Regex giving incorrect results

Tags: javascript, regex

Working in Javascript attempting to use a regular expression to capture data in a string.

My string appears as this starting with the left bracket

```
['ABC']['ABC.5']['ABC.5.1']
```

My goal is to get each piece of the regular expression as a chunk or in array.
I have reviewed and see that the match function might be a good choice.

```
var myString = "['ABC']['ABC.5']['ABC.5.1']";
myString.match(/\[/g]);
```

The output I see is only the [ for each element.

I would like the array to be like this for example

```
myString[0] = ['ABC']
myString[1] = ['ABC.5']
myString[2] = ['ABC.5.1']
```

What is the correct regular expression and or function to get the above-desired output?

Comment: Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559762/get-string-inside-parentheses-removing-parentheses-with-regex), just replace the parenthesis with (escaped) square braces.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets), which I believe is a duplicate.

Comment: Why do you want each result string in its own array?

Comment: Do you want each string to be included as separate array ?

Comment: Try `myString.split(/[\]\[']+/).filter(Boolean);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex with split:

```
\[[^\]]+
```

#### Details

- `\[` - Matches `[`
- `[^\]]+` - Matches anything except `]` one or more time
- `\]` - Matches `]`

```js
let str =  `['ABC']['ABC.5']['ABC.5.1']`

let op = str.split(/(\[[^\]]+\])/).filter(Boolean)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to separate them, you can use a simple expression or better than that you can split them:

```
\[\'(.+?)'\]
```

```js
const regex = /\[\'(.+?)'\]/gm;
const str = `['ABC']['ABC.5']['ABC.5.1']`;
const subst = `['$1']\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/U5Gvay/1/)